# Ruby on Rails: save files in google drive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api, paperclip

I have a Ruby on Rail project but i need save files in an other folder, actually it is saving in a project default folder and the source is "app/public/system/.."

I'm trying save the files in google drive folder and i use: (this is my gemfile resume)

```
gem 'paperclip', '~>  5.1.0'
gem 'paperclip-googledrive-new'
gem 'google-api-client', '0.7.1', require: 'google/api_client'
```

i did the following instructions to save my files:
https://github.com/shoaibmalik786/paperclip-googledrive-new

My model is some like this:

```
has_attached_file :banner, 
        :storage => :google_drive,
        :google_drive_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/google_drive.yml",
        :google_drive_options => {
            :public_folder_id => "0BxckPDmdZqdpYWgzbnVwUEhPVVU",
            :default_image => "missing.png", 
            :path => proc { |style| "#{style}_#{id}_#{banner.original_filename}"
        }
    }
```

i did the  `rake google_drive:authorize` and didn't have errors and in my google_drive.yml i have the result.. is this :

```
client_id: <%= ENV["154813271628..."] %>
client_secret: <%= ENV["mOfV5821kUY..."] %>
access_token: <%= ENV["ya29.GlutA7bKMLwkHs6rXFYU92vZG..."] %>
refresh_token: <%= ENV["1/rAuECXRz..."] %>
```

Also i used "active_admin" in my aplication The actually error in the aplication is this:

[image]

Thx for any help or more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ENV` configuration is invalid:

```
client_id: <%= ENV["154813271628..."] %>
client_secret: <%= ENV["mOfV5821kUY..."] %>
access_token: <%= ENV["ya29.GlutA7bKMLwkHs6rXFYU92vZG..."] %>
refresh_token: <%= ENV["1/rAuECXRz..."] %>
```

[`Should be`](https://github.com/shoaibmalik786/paperclip-googledrive-new#configuration):

```
client_id: <%= ENV["CLIENT_ID"] %>
client_secret: <%= ENV["CLIENT_SECRET"] %>
access_token: <%= ENV["ACCESS_TOKEN"] %>
refresh_token: <%= ENV["REFRESH_TOKEN"] %>
```